# What is the difference between Solr vs Websolr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, heroku

I am researching on full text search engine and I installed Sunspot which makes use of Apache Solr library. We host on Heroku and they offer a Websolr addon which confused me.

Can I use Sunspot without WebSolr on heroku?

**Also Can anyone let me know where to find the websolr api key when i add the heroku websolr addon?**

Comment: api_key is probably in your environment. `heroku config --long --app myapp`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is not a library. It's a stand-alone Java search server. [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) *is* a library, a Ruby client for Solr. [WebSolr](http://websolr.com/) is a service that provides a hosted Solr instance. If you don't use Heroku's Websolr add-on, you'll have to provide your own Solr instance hosted somewhere else.

Comment: Nick from Websolr here and, yes: exactly this.